# How do you append new children and scrollbar to the bottom of a parent div?

Tags: css, flexbox, chat

I am making a chat application. Users submit a message and it fills in the bottom of the chat log. A new message will replace it at the bottom and push it up. When the messages exceed the height of the log, a scrollbar will appear. New messages should still appear by default, i.e. the scrollbar should be anchored to the bottom unless otherwise moved.

I'm having trouble doing this. Intuitively I want to do

```
.chatlog {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

but apparently flex-end and overflow: auto are incompatible. I have tried:

```
.chatlog {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
.chatlog:first-child {
   margin-top: auto;
}
```

but no success. I have also tried adding an .anchor div at the bottom of .chatlog with

```
.chatlog {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-anchor: none;
}
.anchor {
   overflow-anchor: auto;
   height: 1px;
}
```

I don't feel like this is an uncommon requirement considering how many websites have some kind of chat interface, but I haven't found any working solutions.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML code !

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a container:

```css
html {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}

body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.chatlog {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   overflow-y: auto;
   min-height: 100%;
   background: lightgrey;
}

.chatlog .msg-container.me {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}

.chatlog .msg-container .msg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.chatlog .msg-container.other .msg {
  background: white;
}

.chatlog .msg-container.me .msg {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'container'>
  <div class = 'chatlog'>
    <div class = 'msg-container other'>
      <div class = 'msg'>Hi</div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'msg-container me'>
      <div class = 'msg'>Hi, how are you?</div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'msg-container other'>
      <div class = 'msg'>Me? I'm fine. How are you doing?</div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'msg-container me'>
      <div class = 'msg'>Same here.</div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'msg-container other'>
      <div class = 'msg'>OK, bye</div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'msg-container me'>
      <div class = 'msg'>Bye</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```